# How could one implement std::auto_ptr's copy constructor?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, copy-constructor, auto-ptr

Back on my crazy [AutoArray thingy](https://bitbucket.org/BillyONeal/pevfind/src/64bc8a6e3d87/pevFind/Win32AutoArray.hpp)... (quoting important bits from there:

```
class AutoArray
{
    void * buffer;
public:
    //Creates a new empty AutoArray
    AutoArray();
    //std::auto_ptr copy semantics
    AutoArray(AutoArray&); //Note it can't be const because the "other" reference
                           //is null'd on copy...
    AutoArray& operator=(AutoArray);
    ~AutoArray();
    //Nothrow swap
    // Note: At the moment this method is not thread safe.
    void Swap(AutoArray&);
};
```

)

Anyway, trying to implement the copy constructor. There's a piece of client code (not yet committed into bitbucket because it won't build) that looks like this:

```
AutoArray NtQuerySystemInformation(...) { ... };

AutoArray systemInfoBuffer = NtQuerySystemInformation(...);
```

This fails because the copy constructor takes a non-`const` reference as an argument .... but I don't see how you could modify the copy constructor to take a `const` reference, given that the source `AutoArray` used in the assignment is modified (and therefore wouldn't be `const`). You can't modify things to use pass by value of course, because it's the copy constructor and that'd be an infinite loop!

If I was using `auto_ptr`, this would be valid:

```
std::auto_ptr NtQuerySystemInformation(...) { ... };

std::auto_ptr systemInfoBuffer = NtQuerySystemInformation(...);
```

How then, can a class with `auto_ptr`'s copy semantics be possible?

Comment: Just FYI, your code causes multiple definition errors in VS2008 unless I add `inline` in front of the `std::swap` specialization.

Comment: I notice you keep mentioning thread safety. You can't just pick one method to make thread-safe, though. If you really want this to be thread safe, all access to `buffer` needs to be atomic. It needs to be a `boost::/std::atomic<void*>` instead. Imagine someone calls swap while another thread just accesses it with some other method, you'd have a problem. (Again, swap will likely need a mutex, so you'd just mutex every method.) But just wanted to make sure you weren't going to try to protect one function and not any others.

Comment: @GMan: When I saw that it was impossible to make a thread-safe swap I threw out the pretense of thread safety on this. If someone wants thread safety on this they're probably better off controlling it using  synchronization primitives at a higher level than my crappy `WindowsApi::AutoArray` class :)

Comment: @Praetorian: Yep --  didn't notice that problem until I tested with more than one object file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`auto_ptr` uses a dirty trick.

I'll use a dumbed-down class named `auto_int` to demonstrate just the copy construction functionality without bringing in any complexities introduced by templates or inheritance.  I think the code is mostly correct, but it's untested.  Our basic `auto_int` look something like this:

```
class auto_int
{
public:

    auto_int(int* p = 0) : p_(p) { }

    ~auto_int() { delete p_; }

    // copy constructor taking a non-const reference:
    auto_int(auto_int& other) 
        : p_(other.release()) { }

    int* release() 
    {
        int* temp = p_;
        p_ = 0;
        return temp;
    }

private:

    int* p_;
};
```

With this basic `auto_int`, we can't copy a temporary object.  Our goal is to be able to write something like:

```
auto_int p(auto_int(new int()));
```

What we can do is use a helper class.  For `auto_ptr`, this is called `auto_ptr_ref`.  We'll call ours `auto_int_ref`:

```
class auto_int;

class auto_int_ref 
{
public:
    auto_int_ref(auto_int* p) : p_(p) { }

    auto_int& ref() { return *p_; }

private:
    auto_int* p_;
};
```

Basically, an instance of this class just stores a pointer to an `auto_int` and allows us to use it as a "reference" to an `auto_int`.

Then in our `auto_int` class we need two additional functions.  We need another constructor that takes an `auto_int_ref` and we need a conversion operator that allows an `auto_int` to be implicitly converted to an `auto_int_ref`:

```
auto_int(auto_int_ref other)
    : p_(other.ref().release()) { }

operator auto_int_ref() { return this; }
```

This will allow us to "copy" a temporary while still having the copy constructor take a non-const reference.  If we look again at our sample code:

```
auto_int p(auto_int(new int()));
```

What happens is we construct a new temporary `auto_int` and pass `new int()` to the constructor that takes an `int*`.  This temporary is then converted to an `auto_int_ref` that points to it, using the `operator auto_int_ref()`, and the `auto_int` constructor that takes an `auto_int_ref` is used to initialize `p`.

Comment: +1.  Didn't notice before that `auto_ptr_ref` is involved in return by value even when the template parameter does not change.  I always thought it was just for converting `auto_ptr<Derived>` to `auto_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: Note that this trick (called the Colvin-Gibbons trick) has been superseded by proper move semantics in C++0x. The `auto_ptr` class is deprecated in favor of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @In silico: Yes -- if I could use C++0x I'd be done. But unfortunately I need to support Win2k, which means I need to build using VS2008, which means I don't get C++0x features.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Right, it's a note to everyone else who are using a C++0x compilers. :-)

Comment: @In silico:  Thanks for the Colvin-Gibbons name; I wasn't familiar with that.  It's a fun trick.

Comment: @James McNellis: It's a fun trick indeed. Especially since it's an apparent "violation" of the "one user-defined implicit conversion" rule (it [requires 2 or 3 conversions for it to work](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2000/n1232.pdf)). I believe the wording in the current C++ standard has been already changed a while ago to allow `auto_ptr` to "work".

Comment: Boost.Ref is essentially this trick extracted and served as a standalone for reuse.

Comment: @James McNellis: Implemented ( [hpp](https://bitbucket.org/BillyONeal/pevfind/src/ed3a0f5c37c4/pevFind/Win32AutoArray.hpp) [cpp](https://bitbucket.org/BillyONeal/pevfind/src/ed3a0f5c37c4/pevFind/Win32AutoArray.cpp) ). Thanks!

Comment: In my view, auto_int(auto_int&)  is a move-constructor because (1) it takes a non-const reference and (2) it clears the state of the RHS  object. But then why isn't the implicitly generated copy-constructor auto_int(const auto_int&) called in the case of auto_int p(auto_int(new int())); ?

Comment: @Sumant:  Yes, this is a primitive, pre-C++11 way to get move-like semantics.  There is no implicitly-declared copy constructor in this scenario because there is a user-declared copy constructor that suppresses it:  `auto_int(auto_int&)` is a copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

`auto_ptr`'s copy ctor works by *taking ownership away* from the passed-in object.  This is also a big part of the reason why `auto_ptr` can't be used in a `vector` or other STL collections.

This is not how most copy constructors work.  Usually your copy constructor will just clone the passed-in object, so you can pass a const reference to it.  But `auto_ptr` doesnt do this.  It actually modified the original object.  In this sense, its only a copy constructor by name, not by semantics.

### EDIT2:

I'm trying to boil this down a bit.  So effectively you're trying to do something with your class that will allow syntax similar to this:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

auto_ptr<string> gimme()
{
    return auto_ptr<string>(new string("Hello"));
}

int main()
{
    auto_ptr<string> s = gimme();
}
```

...and you're wondering how to get the `s = gimme()` part to work.  Right?

The secret here is in a proxy class, `auto_ptr_ref` described by the Standard in 20.4.5 whose purpose is "to allow auto_ptr objects to be passed to and returned from functions.":

```
namespace std {
  template <class Y> struct auto_ptr_ref {};
  template<class X> class auto_ptr {
  public:
    typedef X element_type;

    // 20.4.5.1 construct/copy/destroy:
    explicit auto_ptr(X* p =0) throw();
    auto_ptr(auto_ptr&) throw();
    template<class Y> auto_ptr(auto_ptr<Y>&) throw();
    auto_ptr& operator=(auto_ptr&) throw();
    template<class Y> auto_ptr& operator=(auto_ptr<Y>&) throw();
    auto_ptr& operator=(auto_ptr_ref<X> r) throw();
    ˜auto_ptr() throw();
    // 20.4.5.2 members:
    X& operator*() const throw();
    X* operator->() const throw();
    X* get() const throw();
    X* release() throw();
    void reset(X* p =0) throw();
    // 20.4.5.3 conversions:
    auto_ptr(auto_ptr_ref<X>) throw();
    template<class Y> operator auto_ptr_ref<Y>() throw();
    template<class Y> operator auto_ptr<Y>() throw();
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know how `auto_ptr` works. How would one implement the copy constructor though? The function call in the client code like I have above works if I change the function to return an `auto_ptr`, but it doesn't work if I have it return `AutoArray`. `auto_ptr` can't take a `const` reference to it's copy constructor either, because it modifies the argument from which it's being copied.

Comment: (In response to edit): I know it's only a copy constructor in name, but the code I have above (returning an `auto_ptr` from a function) certainly works/is valid.

Comment: @Billy:  Maybe I'm getting stuck on "How then, can a class with auto_ptr's copy semantics be possible?" but I'm not understanding how I didn't answer your question?  We must be talking about different things?

Comment: I can return an `auto_ptr` from a function by value. That requires that the `auto_ptr` need to have some form of copy constructor that lets you assign the return value of the function into some `auto_ptr` variable. But with a plain non-`const` copy constructor, that's not possible, because the return value from the function is a temporary, and you're not allowed to bind a reference to a temporary. So there's got to be some non-obvious form of proxy/template magic going on inside `auto_ptr` that makes it work...

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit conversion from `T*` to `std::auto_ptr<T>`.  I'm guessing you do have an implicit conversion constructor from `NTSTATUS` handle to `AutoArray`.  But if that conversion creates a temporary, that temporary can't be copied.

If you use direct initialization rather than copy initialization, your "problem" may go away.

```
AutoArray systemInfoBuffer( ntDll.NtQuerySystemInformation(
  Dll::NtDll::SystemProcessInformation) );
```

Comment: `NtQuerySystemInformation` in this case is not the one defined inside `ntdll.dll`, it's a wrapper function I wrote to abstract away buffer management of the actual call in `Ntdll.dll`. Changing assignment out with a more direct copy constructor call doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Ah, oops.  Might have noticed the function documentation wasn't a class member.  So does the function return an `AutoArray` by value?  Or does it return, say, a different specialization of the same primary class template?

Comment: Yes, it returns an `AutoArray` by value.