# "No matching function for call error" with g++

Tags: c++, g++

I have a class A

```
template<typename T>
class A : public std::auto_ptr<T>
{
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> Super;
public:
    A() : Super() { }
    A(T* t) : Super(t) { }
    A(A<T>& o) : Super(o) { }
    ...
};
```

and IConstEnumerator

```
template<typename T>
struct IConstEnumerator
{
    ...   
virtual IEnumerator<T>* GetEnumerator() = 0;
virtual IConstEnumerator<T>* GetEnumerator() const = 0;      
};
```

When I run this code

```
AP< IConstEnumerator<IPort> > pe = node.GetPorts().GetEnumerator(); ;
```

I got errors from not finding correct match with g++ compiler.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘AIR::A<AIR::IConstEnumerator<AIR::IPort> >::AP(AIR::A<AIR::IConstEnumerator<AIR::IPort> >)’
note: candidates are: AIR::A<T>::A(AIR::A<T>&) [with T = AIR::IConstEnumerator<AIR::IPort>]
note:                 AIR::A<T>::A(T*) [with T = AIR::IConstEnumerator<AIR::IPort>]
```

What's wrong with the class A? It works well with MSVC.

#### EDIT

Using copy constructor explicitly seems to solve this issue. `A< IConstEnumerator<IPort> > pe(node.GetPorts().GetEnumerator())`

Comment: What is the `...` in `AP< IConstEnumerator<IPort> > pe = ... ;`?

Comment: And what is the relation of `AP` to `A`? Is that a typo?

Comment: More information is needed: Please provide a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem (and try to make it as small as possible).  There are a dozen things that could cause this problem.  (My attempt at psychic debugging below was obviously not the right answer given later updates.)

Answer (score 3):

Your `A` copy constructor takes its argument by non-const reference:

```
A(A<T>& o) : Super(o) { }
      ^ not const
```

Your example probably tries to copy a temporary object and the non-const reference can't bind to the temporary object.  Visual C++ has an evil extension that allows this to work; you have to be careful to avoid relying on that extension if you want your code to be portable.

If you are trying to mimic `auto_ptr`'s copy constructor, you need to also implement something similar to `auto_ptr_ref`, which is used as a helper to allow copying temporary `auto_ptr`s.  I describe how this is accomplished in the accepted answer to [How could one implement `std::auto_ptr`'s copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514124/how-could-one-implement-stdauto-ptrs-copy-constructor)

For what it's worth, deriving from `std::auto_ptr` is a bit odd; consider using composition instead of inheritance, if you can (there isn't a whole lot in `std::auto_ptr` that you'd benefit from by deriving from it anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Without the exact code that actually causes the error it's hard to know for sure, but I suspect that from `AIR::A<T>::A(AIR::A<T>&)` what happening is you're trying to pass a temporary (possibly implicit) object into `AIR::A<T>::A` and MSVC lets you bind the temporary to the non-const reference parameter, while g++ quite properly prohibits this. Can you make the parameter `const`?

Comment: I think your assessment is correct, but I assume the copy c'tor takes a non-const reference on purpose, to mimic the semantics of `std::auto_ptr`. Of course, why anyone is using `std::auto_ptr` in new code is anyone's guess...

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you're lacking `A(A<T> const & o)`.

VS (incorrectly) permits getting a non-const reference to a temporary, g++ behaves properly

Answer (score 0):

It looks compiler talks that it cannot choose right function: constructor `A` from pointer `A<T>::A(T*)` or copy constructor `A<T>::A(A<T> &)`. Maybe it worth to change definition  to `explicit A(T* t) : Super(t) { }`