# "no match for ‘operator=’" error with g++

Tags: c++, g++

I have a class AP

```
template<typename T>
class AP : public std::auto_ptr<T>
{
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> Super;
public:
    AP() : Super() { }
    AP(T* t) : Super(t) { }
    AP(AP<T>& o) : Super(o) { }
};
```

And a function to return it.

```
namespace AIR {
namespace Tests {

namespace
{

    AP<A> CreateGraph()
    {
    AP<A> top(A::Create("xyz").release());
        ...
    return top;
    }

    AP<A> top; 
    top = CreateGraph();
```

When I compile the code

```
AP<A> top; 
top = CreateGraph();
```

I got this error message

```
no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘top = AIR::Tests::<unnamed>::CreateGraph()()’
```

I added this operator to the AP class, but it doesn't work.

```
AP<T>& operator=(AP<T>& o) { (*(Super*)this) = o; return *this; }
```

What's wrong with the class?

### EDIT

`top.reset(CreateGraph().release())` solved this issue.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by creating a class derived from `std::auto_ptr`?  It would likely be easier to create your own smart pointer class, not derived from `std::auto_ptr`, that perhaps uses a data member of type `std::auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

`CreateGraph()` returns by value, thus a `CreateGraph()` function call is an rvalue.

Because the `std::auto_ptr` copy assignment operator takes its argument by non-const reference, the implicitly declared `AP` copy assignment operator takes its argument by non-const reference.

A non-const reference can only bind to an lvalue, hence the error.

As I explained in [an answer to one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251007/no-matching-function-for-call-error-with-g/5251099#5251099), if you want to have `std::auto_ptr`-like copying (where the actual copy constructor takes its argument by non-const reference), you also need to implement something similar to `std::auto_ptr_ref`.

I explain how `std::auto_ptr` uses this helper class to allow copying of rvalues in the accepted answer to [How could one implement `std::auto_ptr`'s copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514124/how-could-one-implement-stdauto-ptrs-copy-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be?

```
AP<T>& operator=(const AP<T>& o)
```

Comment: No – since `auto_ptr` transfers ownership.

Comment: Ok, but I guess that it's understandable that top = CreateGraph() reports a compile error then, CreateGraph doesn't return a reference and operator= excepts one. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: the problem is that the return value from `CreateGraph()` is a temporary object, and you can't bind temporaries to non-const references. If the assignment operator took a const reference, then it would work - but that's not an option because of `auto_ptr` and its unconventional assignment behaviour.

Comment: @Mike Yea, got it. So the intended behavior of the auto_ptr is to disallow cloning of a pointer so that the "reference count" is always 1?

Comment: that's right - you can transfer ownership from one pointer to another, but you can't have two pointers owning the same object. Sadly, this idea doesn't quite fit in with the rest of the language. C++0x will implement this properly with move semantics and `unique_ptr`; until then, we must put up with the quirky behaviour of `auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace

```
AP<A> top; 
top = CreateGraph();
```

to

```
AP<A> top(CreateGraph());
```