# 'no matching function for call to' error with g++ : constructor or operator = not matching?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, auto-ptr

I have a assignment operator.

```
AP<T>& operator=(AP<T>& o) {Super::operator=(o); return *this; }
```

When I expect the g++ compiler finds this operator for this code.

```
AP<System> to = System::Create();
```

I got compilation error.

```
no matching function for call to ‘H::AP<H::System>::AP(H::AP<H::System>)’
ap.cpp:13: note: candidates are: H::AP<T>::AP(H::AP<U>&) [with U = H::System, T = H::System]
ap.cpp:12: note:                 H::AP<T>::AP(H::AP<T>&) [with T = H::System]
ap.cpp:11: note:                 H::AP<T>::AP(T*) [with T = H::System]
```

Why is this? MSVC compiles this code without problem.

The source is as follows.

```
#include <memory>

namespace H {

template<typename T>
class AP : public std::auto_ptr<T>
{
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> Super;
public:
    template<typename U> AP<T>& operator=(AP<U>& o) { Super::operator=(o.release()); return *this; }
    AP<T>& operator=(AP<T>& o) { Super::operator=(o); return *this; }
};

class System {
public:
    static AP<System> Create(); 
};

AP<System> System::Create()
{
    AP<System> a(new System()); 
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    AP<System> to = System::Create();
}
};
```

### ADDED

With `AP(const AP<T>& o) : Super(o) { }`, I got those errors.

```
ap.cpp: In copy constructor ‘H::AP<T>::AP(const H::AP<T>&) [with T = H::System]’:
ap.cpp:33:   instantiated from here
ap.cpp:12: error: passing ‘const H::AP<H::System>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::auto_ptr<_Tp>::operator std::auto_ptr_ref<_Tp1>() [with _Tp1 = H::System, _Tp = H::System]’ discards qualifiers
```

### ADDED2

I don't know it's the best solution, but this code seems to work.

```
int main()
{
  H::AP<H::System> tox(H::System::Create().release());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this not an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251007/ ?

Answer (score 1):

`AP<System> to = System::Create();` looks for a copy constructor as Adam said.

Using `const` will solve your problem. Apart from that temporaries cannot be bound to non-const references.

For example:

```
AP<System> &ref = AP<System>();
```

won't compile on gcc if the parameter of your copy c-tor is not a reference to `const`. However on MSVC++ the above code would compile because MSVC++(2008 or before) allows temporaries to get bound to non-const reference (evil extension).

However if you try to replicate `auto_ptr`'s copy c-tor [you need to implement something similar to `auto_ptr_ref` (in order to allow copying temporary `auto_ptr` objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514124/how-could-one-implement-stdauto-ptrs-copy-constructor/4514204#4514204)

Comment: Temporaries do not bind to non-const references in MSVC2010. You need to clarify which versions exactly do have this extension.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a copy constructor, not an `operator=`: read the error message more carefully.  Your copy constructor is not defined correctly: you need to defined it as a `const` reference:

```
AP(const AP<T>& o) : Super(o) { }
// ^^^^^
```

Comment: While correct, notice he's using `auto_ptr`. He'll need to perform the same trick it does to handle temporaries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got some errors with the const added.