# In C++03 auto_ptr why isn't compiler generated copy-ctor called?

Tags: emulation, auto-ptr, c++03, move-constructor

I understand how `auto_ptr` works in C++03. It is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514124/how-could-one-implement-stdauto-ptrs-copy-constructor/4514204#4514204) trick. The trick uses a user-defined conversion to steal the pointer from one object to another when code such as this `auto_int p(auto_int(new int()));` is written. However, I've several questions in this regard.

1. Why isn't the compiler-generated copy-ctor called?
2. Why does the user-defined conversion take precedence over a compiler-generated copy-ctor?
3. Is there a compiler-generated copy-ctor to begin with?
4. If not, what language rule suppresses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't the compiler-generated copy-ctor called?

Because the class already supplied a copy-constructor, a mutable one which is still valid, so the compiler does not generate a default one.

> Why does the user-defined conversion take precedence over a compiler-generated copy-ctor?

There is no compiler generated copy-constructor.

> Is there a compiler-generated copy-ctor to begin with?

Finally! Nope, there isn't.

> If not, what language rule suppresses it?

It's 12.8.2:

> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

And 12.8.4:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly.

Comment: As far as I understand copy-ctor must have a const parameter. So you are suggesting that a non-const parameter still makes it a "copy-ctor"? I mean, you can define both if you want. Then which one is the copy-ctor?

Comment: @Sumant: See the edits for the standard references, a copy-constructor needs not have a const parameter. I'd guess if you define both, then overload resolution applies.