# Why auto_ptr unnormal behavior

Tags: c++, auto, pointers

First please make sure you know the std::auto_ptr once have 3 versions.

The 1st version of std::auto_ptr which look like this:

```
template<class T>
class auto_ptr 
{
public:
    explicit auto_ptr(T *p = 0): pointee(p) {}

    // copy constructor member
    // template: initialize a new auto_ptr with any compatible auto_ptr
    template<class U> auto_ptr(auto_ptr<U>& rhs): pointee(rhs.release()) {}

    ~auto_ptr() { delete pointee; }

    // assignment operator
    // member template assign from any compatible auto_ptr 
    template<class U> auto_ptr<T>& operator=(auto_ptr<U>& rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            reset(rhs.release());
        }
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() const { return *get(); }
    T* operator->() const { return get(); } 

    // return value of current dumb pointer
    T* get() const { return pointee; } 

    // relinquish ownership of current dumb pointer and return its value
    T* release() { T* p = pointee;  pointee = 0; return p; }                            

    // delete owned pointer,assume ownership of p
    void reset(T *p = 0)
    { 
        if (p != pointee) 
        {
            delete pointee;
            pointee = p;
        }
    }
private:
    T* pointee;
};
```

Only interface, while the implementation is easy.

My code like this:

```
auto_ptr<int> foo()
{
    auto_ptr<int> p(new int(1));
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    auto_ptr<int> p;
    p = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

In my point of view, my test code can not pass compiler. But it passed, and when I run it, it broken for delete a ponter twice.

I trace the assembly code and find the flow like below, memory address is low 16 bit for short.

```
ctor: f8e4    
new: 6bf0
ctor: f7d4

copy ctor: f7d4  ->  f80c
dctor: f7d4 (NULL)
delete: 0

lea ecx, [ebp-0ECh] // f8e4: memory-> 6bf0

dctor: f80c (6bf0)
delete: 6bf0

dctor: f8e4 (6bf0)   // twice delete
```

It seems that the code : p = foo(); ctor a temporary object and it hold the memory which new in foo().

The key point is, why p = foo() just change p.pointee, other than call p.operator=() ?

I add implementation of 1st auto_ptr.

---

Talking with net friend, he pointed that **mybe compiler generate**:

```
auto_ptr<T>& operator=(auto_ptr<T>& rhs)
```

other than use

```
template<class U> auto_ptr<T>& operator=(auto_ptr<U>& rhs);
```

I find that std::auto_ptr have two operator=. And I test add it to interface manually, while complier tips: "'auto_ptr' can not convert to 'auto_ptr &'".

that's the Key!!!  then I need to find Why!

---

When user not define operator= for the class type, compiler will generate one. And compare with other operator=，choose a more special one!

**Solved! Thinks for all your answer! Thanks for all your comments!**

Comment: "The implementation is easy"?? Have you *seen* any implementations of `auto_ptr`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Yes, in <memory> file, you can find it in gcc or vs, i have seen the version of vs.

Comment: @mi2think If you still think it's easy then you haven't dug deep enough to get to the [`auto_ptr_ref`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514204/241631) madness.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr`, `std::auto_ptr` is broken and deprecated.

Comment: About the 3 versions of `auto_ptr`: http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/auto_ptr-update.html . Now, why do you show version 1? it was abandoned in 1996 for version 2, which was in turn abandoned in 1998 for version 3, are you on a pre-Standard compiler? Also in `auto_ptr<int> p(new A(1));` what is this `A`?

Comment: @mi2think Your code doesn't compile because of this `auto_ptr<int> p(new A(1));`. Changing it to `auto_ptr<int> p(new int(1));` causes it to compile and run without errors. Please post the definition of `A`.

Comment: @Praetorian I say it easy just for 1st's interface is simple, and i do know the auto_ptr and auto_ptr_ref story. i have changed, thinks!

Comment: @gx_ Yes, I saw it and just want test 1st auto_ptr for reappear
the problems once C++ standards committee encountered. I have fixed the error "A"

Comment: @mi2think I have just posted an answer but I see that you edited your answer a few seconds before... ^^'

Comment: @gx_ Aha! You get the key of my problem! Thanks! and I understand that  when user not define operator= for the original type, compiler will  generate one. And compare with other operator=，choose a more special one!  Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I have understood your issue correctly, but your interface actually does *not* define the *copy* assignment operator (nor the *copy* constructor), because the "*template* copy op=" is not a true copy op= (and the "template copy ctor" is not a true copy ctor).

Here's a simple example to show the problem:

```
#include <cstdio>
using std::puts;

struct M {
    M& operator=(M const&) {
        puts("M::operator=(M const&)");
        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename T> class Foo {
    M m;
    template<typename U> friend class Foo; // (needed for m = rhs.m; below)
public:
    template<typename U> Foo& operator=(Foo<U> const& rhs) {
        puts("[template] Foo<T>::operator=(Foo<U> const&)");
        m = rhs.m; // calls M's op=
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    puts("===");
    Foo<int> a;
    Foo<double> b;
    a = b;
    puts("---");
    Foo<int> c;
    Foo<int> d;
    c = d;
    puts("===");
}
```

That prints:

```
===
[template] Foo<T>::operator=(Foo<U> const&)
M::operator=(M const&)
---
M::operator=(M const&)
===
```

Why is there only one line for the second assignment? That's because `c = d;` calls `Foo<int>::operator=(Foo<int> const&)` i.e. the true *copy* assignment operator, and since we have *not* declared it (only a *template* version) the compiler generates it automatically (which does a member-wise assignment, hence the call to `M::operator=`).

Thus, me must add it explicitly to the class:

```
    // ...
    Foo& operator=(Foo const& other) {
        puts("[non-template] Foo<T>::operator=(Foo<T> const&)");
        m = other.m;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and then it prints:

```
===
[template] Foo<T>::operator=(Foo<U> const&)
M::operator=(M const&)
---
[non-template] Foo<T>::operator=(Foo<T> const&)
M::operator=(M const&)
===
```

So, in your example, `p = foo();` does not invoke your user-defined `template<class U> auto_ptr<T>& operator=(auto_ptr<U>& rhs)` but the implicitly-generated version that simply assigns the `pointee` member (without releasing the source).